# May I know which one is correct

Tags: word-choice, syntactic-analysis

May I know which one is correct, "Our family got a surprised time" or "Our family got a surprising time" or Our family got a surprise time"? Thank you so much.

Comment: None of them are correct. The only salvageable sentence is the second one; it should be reworded as follows: “Our family ***had*** a surprising time.” Even with the rewording it still doesn’t make that much sense.

Answer (score 0):

None of the three are correct.

"Our family got a surprised time" incorrectly suggests that the time itself was surprised.

"Our family got a surprise time" is grammatically incorrect as "surprise" is a noun and therefore cannot describe "time" (although nouns are often used in conversational speech to describe another noun, it is technically incorrect and does not work well in this situation).

"Our family got a surprising time" is grammatically correct, but the use of "got" is awkward in typical situations unless you meant to say that your family actually *received* a surprising time. However, even if that was the case, I would advise against using "got."

"Our family had a surprising time" would be the correct way of saying what I assume you wish to say.

Comment: Attributive nouns are a part of the language - they aren’t always “technically incorrect”.

Comment: I. Ylisse, thank you so much for your detailed explanation.